# jQuery: Drag/Adjust image postion in a circular div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to user's profile photo in a circular div. Similar to what user can do with facebook's profile picture or cover image.

> Note: Here image is a background image of div. Not inside `<img>`.

How can make user drag/adjust image functionality for circular div?

**CSS for Circular Div**

```
.circular {
    width: 6em;
    height: 6em;
    border-radius: 3em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3em;
    -moz-border-radius: 3em;
    background: url('../img/id.jpg') no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a div like display and into put your image. 
The parent div need to be rounded and with overflow hidden and for the image child you can use the draggable() method of jquery ui.
Look here for examples : [JQuery UI Examples](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

---

This is one example but webkit overflow hidden is bugged.
[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2UBaf/)
you can try with one mask for fixxing bug

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(".avatar").draggable(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jqueryUI `draggable()` method:

```
$('image_to_drag').draggable();
```

Comment: 'image_to_drag' is a background image of circular div